# Hibernate extend entity - Object was not of the specified subclass - Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I would like to build field which can be String, Boolean or Long. In this case I tried use generics type and inheratiance. All code compiles correctly but when I want to get some parameters from database I got a error like:

> Object [id=1] was not of the specified subclass
>   [unity.app.domain.Parameter] : Discriminator: 1",

What is more if I want to use post method to adding parameter to DB I got error like this:

> "Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   unity.app.domain.Parameter]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `unity.app.domain.Parameter` (no Creators, like
>   default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to
>   concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type
>   information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",

How to resolve this problem?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "parameter", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Parameter<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    private T value;

    @Transient
    public abstract T getValue();

    public abstract void setValue(T value);
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "boolean")
public class BooleanValue extends Parameter<Boolean> {

    @Column(name = "bool_value")
    private Boolean booleanValue;

    getValue()/setValue()[...]
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "long")
public class LongValue extends Parameter<Long> {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "string")
public class StringValue extends Parameter<String> {}
```

I am using postgresql and this is my table "parameter":

```
  id BIGINT,
  code VARCHAR,
  name VARCHAR,
  description VARCHAR,
  bool_value BOOLEAN,
  string_value VARCHAR,
  long_value BIGINT
```

Comment: Can you solve it? I have the same problem